# AppleScript cannot access elements of SecurityAgent

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a AppleScript to enter an admin password into the window prompt, but the script cannot find any elements of process "SecurityAgent"

Here's a diagnostic script I used to retrieve all of the items under "SecurityAgent" and its result, which is nothing.

I verified from Accessibility Inspector that the window is indeed under the process "SecurityAgent"

[Diagnostic Code and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1kCk.png)

If I try to access any element of window 1, the result would be:

```
   "Can't get window 1 of process \"SecurityAgent\". Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
```

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way is to wait until the process `SecurityAgent` has started

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.5
    repeat until exists process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        // do something
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, but I left a long delay before I ran the diagnostic code. I even left the window open while rerunning it, with the same result.

If I ran the code with the SecurityAgent window suppressed (or non-existent) then it would throw an error along "Cannot find process SecurityAgent"

Comment: Of course this code assumes a preceding line which evokes the window to enter the password for example a `do shell script` line `with administrator privileges`. I'm using this code in many scripts.

Comment: Okay, so I wasn't patient enough. Window 1 of SecurityAgent becomes accessible after waiting ~60 seconds. Strange

Comment: Nvm, it's not consistent. Sometimes it shows up after waiting, sometimes it doesn't show up after waiting 30 minutes...

Comment: I have the same issue. A workaround that works for me is to manually click the window: as soon as I do that, the window is somehow associated with the process. I have not (yet) found a way to do this automatically. E.g. "Set frontmost to true" does not seem to help.

Comment: In the Accessibility Inspector, the window is listed under AXMainWindow as well as AXFocusedWindow, despite that AXWindows is an empty list. So perhaps it is possible to get the main or focussed window somehow with Applescript.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and to me it seems like a bug.

Strangely enough, when examining the Application with the Accessibility inspector, it has 0 windows, but despite that, the value of AXMainWindow as well as AXFocusedWindow points to the visible window.

[image: Screenshot of Accessibility Inspector]

Unfortunately, the following Applescript will result in a `missing value` for the variable `theWindow`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theWindow to the value of attribute "AXMainWindow" of process "SecurityAgent"
end tell
```

In rare cases, the window is known, and `theWindow` takes the value `window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"`.

The good news is that there seems a workaround: as soon as you click the window, AppleScript can find it!

The easiest workaround is to manually click the window.

Of course, it should be possible to automate that too...
For some reason, the following code did not work for me:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        activate
        set frontmost to true
        click at {200, 250}
    end tell
end tell
```

Fortunately, the following code did work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    AST click at {200, 250}
end tell
```

However, this does require you to install the [Applescript Toolbox](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/), which is only available for macOS up to 10.13. Since macOS 10.14, third party Applescript libraries are no longer supported.